# Xslt to move footnote tag to end of parent

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Here is my xml file

```
<chapter>
<section>
    <info>
    <title>footnote</title>
    </info>
    <para>welcome to xml footnote</para>
    <para>something</para>
    <para> something.......
    <footnote role="end-ch-note" xml:id="b-9781472580740-0000409" label="1">
    <para xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001874">
     somrthing......</para>
     </footnote>something.....
     </para>         
     <para> something.......
    <footnote role="end-ch-note" xml:id="b-9781472580740-0000410" label="2">
    <para xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001875">
     somrthing......</para>
     </footnote>something.....
     </para>
</section>
</chapter>
```

i want all the footnote tag to come down under ?insert item tag

Here is my xsl i convert it into html with following xsl

```
 <xsl:template match="book/chapter">
    <div class="pagebreak">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter[@label]">          
    <div class="pagebreak" id="CT-{@label}">
        <p class="ChapNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>             
        </p>
        <div class="chapterinfo"><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
        </div>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="chapter/info/title">
    <p class="ChapTitle">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>         
     <xsl:template match="footnote[@label]">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>#fn</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@xml:id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <sup>
            <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
        </sup>
    </a>
    <div class="footnote">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>fn</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@xml:id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>            
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>
```

I get out put like below by using xsl i have

```
 <div class="pagebreak" id="CT-2">
 <p class="ChapNumber">2</p>
 <div class="chapterinfo">
 <p class="ChapTitle">International Tax Cooperation and Implications of       Globalization</p>
 <a href="#fnb-9781472580740-0000409">
              <sup>1</sup>
           </a>
  <div class="footnote" id="fnb-9781472580740-0000409">
  <p class="Text">A prior version of this chapter was published     by the Friedrich Ebert Stiftung in its International Policy Analysis series. It draws from my previous work on the subject, which has been supported by the Ford Foundation.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="textindent">something...............</div>
  <div calss="text">something.............</div>
  <a href="#fnb-9781472580740-0000410">
  <sup>2</sup>
  </a>
  <div class="footnote" id="fnb-9781472580740-0000410">
  <p class="Text">A prior version of this chapter was published by the Friedrich Ebert Stiftung in its International Policy Analysis series. It draws from my previous work on the subject, which has been supported by the Ford Foundation.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

i want all the div class="footnote" to come at end of chapter tag 
can any one help me

i want out put like below

```
<div class="chapter">
<div class="section">       
    <div class="title">footnote</div>       
    <p class="textindent">welcome to xml footnote</p>
    <p class="text">something</p>
    <p class="text">something.......
        <a href="#fnb-b-9781472580740-0000409">
              <sup>1</sup>
           </a>            
            something.....
     </p>        
     <p class="text"> something.......
    <a href="#fnb-b-9781472580740-0000410">
              <sup>1</sup>
           </a>
           something.....
     </p>
</div>
<div class="notes">
<div class="footnote" id="fnb-9781472580740-0000409">
            <p class="Text">something.......</p>
           </div>
<div class="footnote" id="fnb-9781472580740-0000410">
            <p class="Text">something.......</p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Could you minimize your example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes below is my xml input<chapter>
 <section>
  <info>
  <title>footnote</title>
  </info>
  <para>welcome to xml footnote</para>
  <para>something</para>
  <para> something.......
  <footnote role="end-ch-note" xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001873" label="1">
  <para xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001874">
   somrthing......</para>
   </footnote>something.....
   </para>   
   <para> something.......
  <footnote role="end-ch-note" xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001874" label="2">
  <para xml:id="b-9781472580740-0001875">
   somrthing......</para>
   </footnote>something.....
   </para>
 </section>
</chapter>

Comment: yes i changed the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following stylesheet produces the wanted output with respect to your footnote-requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <div class="chapter">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <div class="notes">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//footnote[@label]" mode="notes"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <div class="section">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <div class="title">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote[@label]">
        <a href="{concat('#fn',@xml:id)}" id="{@xml:id}">
            <sup><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></sup>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote[@label]" mode="notes">
        <div class="footnote" id="{concat('fn',@xml:id)}">
            <a href="{concat('#',@xml:id)}">
                <sup>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                </sup>
            </a>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="notes"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Three points should be mentioned:

a) in normal mode, `<footnote>` places its label-number, linked to the notes-section,

b) footnotes are handled a 2nd time in `notes` mode at the end of a `<chapter>`. In this mode, their text is placed into `<div class="notes">` while the label numbers link back to the calling footnotes in normal text.

c) `<para>`'s are not handled explicitly in `notes` mode; therefore, we only get their respective text and no surrounding `<p>`

Comment: LEU I just trying 2days for this output , I'm just a beginner in xslt   Thank you  so much